# What is a fastest way to do search through xml

Tags: c#, xml, search

Suppose i have an XML file, that i use as local database, like this):

```
<root>
 <address>
  <firstName></firstName>
  <lastName></lastName>
  <phone></phone>
 </address>
</root>
```

I have a couple of questions:
1. *What will be a fastest way to find address(or addresses) in XML where firstName contains 'er' for example?*
2. *Is it possible to do without whole loading of XML file in memory?*

P.S. I am not looking for XML file alternatives, ideally i need a search that not depend on count of addresses in XML file. But i am realist, and it seems to me that it not possible.

**Update:**
I am using .net 4
Thanks for suggestions, but it's more scientific task than practical.. I probably looking for more fastest ways than linq and xmltextreader.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LINQ to Xml works pretty fine:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("myfile.xml");
var addresses = from address in doc.Root.Elements("address")
                where address.Element("firstName").Value.Contains("er")
                select address;
```

**UPDATE:** Try to look at this question on StackOverflow: [Best way to search data in xml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563998/best-way-to-search-data-in-xml-files).

Marc Gravell's accepted answer works using SQL indexing:

> First: how big are the xml files? XmlDocument doesn't scale to "huge"... but can handle "large" OK.
>
> Second: can you perhaps put the data
>   into a regular database structure
>   (perhaps SQL Server Express Edition),
>   index it, and access via regular TSQL?
>   That will usually out-perform an xpath
>   search. Equally, if it is structured,
>   SQL Server 2005 and above supports the
>   xml data-type, which shreds data -
>   this allows you to index and query xml
>   data in the database without having
>   the entire DOM in memory (it
>   translates xpath into relational
>   queries).

**UPDATE 2:** Read also another link taken by the previous question that explains how the structure of the XML affects performances: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/010410.htm

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for *fastest way*. I suppose there is something that will work faster than linq.

Comment: I've run a test with a 24MB XML (about 425k addresses) and it took 534 milliseconds.

Comment: +1 for performance testing with linq, but i believe that there is more fastest way. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer quoting a solution by Marc Gravell. Try to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have .NET 3.5+, consider using [LINQ To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx).

Some sample code to give you some idea:  (code below lifted/modified liberally from the article)

```
IEnumerable<string> addresses =
    from inv in customer.Descendants("Invoice")
    where inv.Attribute("ProductName").StartsWith("er")
    select (string) inv.Attribute("StreetAddress");
```

Comment: Note that `firstName` is not an attribute but an element.

Comment: @AS-CII: thanks, I wasn't paying attention, but rather pointing out a technology and how to use it. Have A Nice Day!

Answer (score 2):

And what about [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) ?
I think it could be the fastest way...

I tried approx 110 MB file and it took about 1,1 sec.
Same file with LinqToXML (above) takes about 3 sec.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("C:\\Temp\\items.xml", settings);

String firstName = "", lastName = "", phone = "";
String lastTagName = "";
Boolean bItemFound = false;
long nCounter = 0;

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

reader.MoveToContent();
// Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            //Console.Write("<{0}>", reader.Name);

            lastTagName = reader.Name;

            if (lastTagName ==  "address")
                nCounter++;

            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            //Console.Write(reader.Value);
            switch (lastTagName)
            {
               case "firstName":
                    firstName = reader.Value.ToString();
                    bItemFound = firstName.Contains("97331");
                    break;
                case "lastName":
                    lastName = reader.Value.ToString();
                    break;
                case "phone":
                    phone = reader.Value.ToString();
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
            //Console.Write("<![CDATA[{0}]]>", reader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
            //Console.Write("<?{0} {1}?>", reader.Name, reader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
            //Console.Write("<!--{0}-->", reader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            //Console.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Document:
        case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
            //Console.Write("<!DOCTYPE {0} [{1}]", reader.Name, reader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
            //Console.Write(reader.Name);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            //Console.Write("</{0}>", reader.Name);
            break;
    }

    if (bItemFound)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n", firstName, lastName, phone);
        bItemFound = false;
    }
}

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
    ts.Milliseconds / 10);
Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
Console.WriteLine("Searched items: {0}", nCounter);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XmlTextReader if you don't want to read the whole file into memory. Such solution will probably run faster, but it will involve more coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm worried you might want to optimize something that might not need it. How many email addresses are we talking about?  Most of the time you would read in the input and build a structure that supports the kind of queries you will be running.

There are trees that can get to the kind of results you are looking for in order log(n) time. And you can store a ton of addresses in even a small amount of memory.

Comment: I am not worry at all, it's more scientific task than practical.

Comment: well, to get all of the data that starts with n letters you will need to read all of the data unless you can assume it's sorted. if it's sorted you can binary search to the correct entry locations and then scan from that point forward. it does not matter if the file is on disk or in memory it's pretty much the same algorithm. it will run faster in memory but if it's too large to fit you can do it all with file pointers and an earliest instance flavor of binary search.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need not to do this on server side, you can do it with regular expressions. But loading the XML on memmory would be faster I think...