# XML file searching

Tags: c#, xml

In my project which i am working on, I am not getting what to do at first.

The project is to search through 100 XML files that are placed in the same folder and the search criteria is as follows:

1. Single valued search
2. two values that are found together in an XML Document(AND)
3. two values, either of which is found in an XML Document(OR)
   and then display the path in which any value exist based on the above criteria.

Comment: This is too broad. Break the problem into small problems and work on each step individually. You can't expect to solve this issue in a few lines or code/one question on SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to search data in xml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563998/best-way-to-search-data-in-xml-files)

Comment: Actually, this probably admits a one-liner in PowerShell. But you'll still have to be more specific about what you mean with "values found". Element contents? Of particular elements? Can you distill that into an XPath expression?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.